# Javascript function does not work more specific? 654564654

Tags: javascript

WHen user clicks on sumbit button, it should check if username value is empty, if it is empty, alert box should be displayed.

It does not work, alert box is not displaying.. could u tell me what is wrong?
thx 
Its not whole html code, only part of it
html :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkForm.js"></script> 
    <body>
 <form method = "post" name="registerForm" action="register.php"  id= "register_form" >
     <input type="text" id="username" name="username" >


  <input type="submit" id="register_button1" onsumbit="return checkForm()" value="Sumbit" >
```

**javascript:**

```
function checkForm()
{
 var username = document.getElementById('username');
 if(username.value == "")
 {
 alert("Name is not entered");
 return false;
 }
 }
```

Comment: Have you tried "== null" ?

Comment: yeah :D I tried now, does not work..

Comment: @brata You can try `username.value.length == 0`, however if your example isn't working, something else must be wrong. What does your console say?

Comment: In the submit input you've spelled submit incorrectly twice. Try changing it to onsubmit

Comment: my console? I dont have a console... Just regular text editor

Comment: @brata On the browser that you are running this code, press ctrl+shift+j in chrome or F12 to open the console.

Answer (score 2):

2 things:

- the `onsubmit` property should be placed on the form and not on the button
- check that you have linked the script correctly; verify the URL.

```html
<script>
    function checkForm() {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username.value == "") {
            alert("Name is not entered");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>

<form method="post" name="registerForm" action="register.php" id="register_form"  onsubmit="return checkForm()">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" />
    <input type="submit" id="register_button1" value="Sumbit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your submit button, and it also needs to be changed to onclick:

```
<input type="submit" id="register_button1" onsumbit="return checkForm()" value="Sumbit" >
```

Change it to:

```
<input type="submit" id="register_button1" onclick="return checkForm()" value="Sumbit" >
```

Answer (score 0):

OK Now it works.. I copied this

```
<script>
    function checkForm() {
        var username = document.getElementById('username');
        if (username.value == "") {
            alert("Name is not entered");
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

in head instead of using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkForm.js"></script>`

I also fixed some errors..
when i am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/checkForm.js"></script>`  it does not work.. weird